# How to execute mongo commands through c#.net

Tags: c#, mongodb

How to execute mongo commands through c#.net,
for example we need to execute sql insert command from c# code for that we have ExecuteNonQuery() is there,

```
SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(strcon);
mycon.Open();
string strquery = "INSERT INT0 studentDetails values('" + txtName.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtQual.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtAge.Text.ToString() + "','" + txtMobile.Text + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strquery, mycon);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

****in that same way how to write c# code for to execute mongodb queries**

Comment: I changed the question description, this question related to mongodb (Nosql), c#.net.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course MongoDB does have all the queries just like SQL.

I would suggest please unlearn SQL and start with cloud. As Clouds like MongoDB go with NO-SQL format. All the tables that are getting created are Schema-less, that is they do not have any specific structure.

Database--> will hold Collections( just like SQL tables).

Through C# we need to get the connection string of your MongoDB server, and get the instances created for Database and collections and execute the query for the methods you want.

A sample code for creating instances and Executing query is,

```
string uri = "mongodb://username:password@servername:portnumber/databasename";

var client = new MongoClient(uri);
var db = client.GetDatabase(databaseName);
var collection = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collectionName);

collection.InsertOne(collectionItem);
```

Unlearn SQL, create an instance for your collection and use the methods instead.

You can see more information at my blog: [MongoDB complete operations in C# -MVC](http://freeprogrammingguides.blogspot.com/2015/12/mongodb-complete-operations-in-c.html)